# How to see the values of elements of a structure in Visual Studio 2008 during debugging?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

For example,

```
structure S{
int a;
int *b;
}s;
```

//now when I try to check the values stored...

```
s->a = ?
s->b[0] = ?
s->b[1] = ?
```

.. and so on

How do I "add watch" or use any other technique to check the values? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question? You don't know how to show the Watch window, or you don't know how to edit things in the Watch window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a value of type `S*` that you want to inspect in the debugger.  The easiest way to do this is simply type the expression which produces the value into the watch window.  So for example if you have a local named `pValue` simply

- Open the Watch Window
- Type 'pValue' into one of the rows
- Expand to see the contents

The tricky part is seeing all of the values in `S::b` as it will be displayed as a single pointer vs. an array.  In order to see the value as an array you just need to tell the debugger how many elements there are.  For example if there were 5 elements you could type the following into the watch window

```
pValue->b,5
```

Expanding that will show you the first 5 `int` values in `pValue->b`